# Wait on condition variable without locking a critical section or SRW

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, synchronization, condition-variable

Is it possible to wait on a condition variable in WinAPI without specifying any critical section or slim reader-writer lock? If not, why? If yes, how?

I know an event can do this. However, I wouldn't like to have both a condition variable and an event. Sometimes I need to wait on it with atomic unlocking/locking. Sometimes it's enough to wait without locking anything.

Comment: No it isn't possible. A condition variable with no associated exclusion lock would be nothing more than something else already provided by the windows api: [an *event*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686915(v=vs.85).aspx). The very reason for using a condition variable rather than an event is the guarantee of atomically releasing the lock when entering the wait state. Not providing a lock, therefore, makes no sense. Further, guaranteeing locked access to whatever shared predicate is crucial on wake, so again, it makes no sense without it.

Comment: @WhozCraig, I've edited the question explaining the situation and why no event.

Comment: not possible. look for next scenario - thread#1 call `if (!x) SleepConditionVariable(&cs);` when thread#2 in concurrent call `x=true; WakeAllConditionVariable(&cs);` without critical section or SRW lock possible that first thread#1 read false from `x`, then thread#2 call `WakeAllConditionVariable` (and this call will no effect because nobody yet wait on cs) and only then thread#1 call `SleepConditionVariable` and will be wait infinite. but if `x` changed only inside critsec ot srw lock - this prevent break between `x` check and `SleepConditionVariable`. may be you need look for `WaitOnAddress`

Comment: in more general - condition variable have no internal state - this is pure list of waiters, unlike event object which have internal state (signaled/not signaled) which synchronized with waiters list. for cs you use **external** state (some variable) which must be synchronized with cs waiters list (via critsec or srw lock). possible another solution `WaitOnAddress` and `WakeByAddress*` where internal state (and waiters list) bind to (and synchronized with) address. but need concrete understand task - what type of synchronization need implement.